# Ansible: Register variable when JSON value equals

Tags: json, ansible

I'm calling a webservice and returning some JSON. I want to conditionally run a subsequent task, based on whether a particular `name` value is found.

For example, set a value `nameExists` if and only if the `values` array contains a `name` field of `myDemo`. So in this case, `nameExists` would be defined:

```
...
"failed": false,
"json": {
  "values": [{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "myDemo"
  },
  {
    "id": "6789",
    "name": "myDemo2"
  }]
},
"msg": "OK (100 bytes)"
...
```

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
# Call API
- name: Call API
  uri:
    url: myURL
    method: POST
  register: apiCheckResult

- name: Debug Auto tags
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ apiCheckResult.json['values'] }}"
  when: item.name == "myDemo"
  register: tagExists
```

This works, in a way, but it gives me the full JSON output, all I need is a true / false.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't (normally) use a `debug` task to set variables. You probably want to use `set_fact`. If I understand your question correctly, you want to set a boolean `tagExists` to `true` if one of the items in the `values` list of the API response contains the `name` `myDemo`.  That might look like this:

```
- set_fact:
    tagExists: "{{ apiCheckResult.json|json_query('values[?name == `myDemo`]') }}"
```

"But wait!", you say, "that's not a boolean!".  While you are correct, you can *treat* it like on.  For example, after having set `tagExists` using that task, you could do this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "The tag exists!"
  when: tagExists
```

This works because a non-empty list evaluates as a `true` value in a boolean context (and an empty list evaluates as `false`).  The `json_query` expression above returns a non-empty list when there is a match, and an empty list otherwise.

If you *really* want a boolean, you could do this instead:

```
- set_fact:
    tagExists: "{{ true if apiCheckResult.json|json_query('values[?name == `myDemo`]') else false }}"
```